# Returning a pointer from a function to main

Tags: c, arrays, function-pointers

Writing a program to find the address of the largest element in an array with 10 integers my code is:

```
int* Largest(int *array, int size);
int main()
{
   int *Ptr, array[10];
   int r, c, num = 1;
   for(r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
       array[r] = num + 1;
   }

   Ptr = Largest(array, 10);
   printf("%p", Ptr);
   return 0;
}

int* Largest(int *array, int size)
{
    int *largest, r;
    for(r = 0; r < size; r++) {
       if(r = 0) {
          largest = &array[0];
       }
       else {
           if(array[r] > *largest) {
               largest = &array[r];
           }
       }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

I dont get any errors or warning when compiling however the program does not do anything and gets stopped automatically by windows.

Comment: Your program looks Ok to me, it must be windows's fault. Did you include the headers?

Comment: How do you know it gets stopped by windows? Are you sure the cmd window isn't just closing because execution finished?

Comment: @clcto nothing happens and a dialog box appears saying lab04.exe has stopped working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You probably didn't include headers you need at least `stdio.h`
2. You have an assignment which very likely shouldn't be

   ```
   if(r = 0)
   ```

   I think this should be

   ```
   if (r == 0)
   ```

   I have seen that some people prevent this kind of problem by doing

   ```
   if (0 == r)
   ```

   since this way the program will fail to compile if you use the `=` operator, and anyway this is not a very good way of doing this, instead you should

   ```
   larget = &array[0];
   for (r = 1 ; r < size ; ++r)
   ```

   and this will be more efficient obviously.

As for the program stopping, you can try to run the `cmd.exe` window and execute your program directly from there.

**Note**: `if (condition1) {} else if (condition2) {}` is valid in c, no need for `if (condition1) {} else {if (condition2) {}}`.

Comment: Okay so the problem was that (r=0) was supposed to be (r == 0) which is a dumb mistake but why didnt that get caught by the compiler?

Comment: If you enable warnings the compiler would tell you to add extra parentheses around the `assignment used as truth value`, at least with `gcc` I have no idea how MSVC compiler works or if it has those warnings.

Comment: @JackV It's a perfectly legal statement, the result of `=` is the value which was assigned, and in C, a truthy statement is anything with a value other than zero, and a falsey one is any statement with a value of 0.

Comment: @JackV: To add onto what Namfuak has said, it *does* have legit uses, for example: `while((c = getc(stdin)) != EOF) /* do something with 'c' */` or `a = b = 5;` (the latter sets *both* `a` and `b` to `5`).

Comment: Why does Windows stop execution? It should just infinite loop.

Comment: Instead of `largest = &array[0];` you could also just use `largest = array;`.

Comment: @clcto It never assigns a value to `largest`, so it's undefined behavior.  As I recall, MSVC automatically sets all variables to zero on initialization which would explain a segfault.

Comment: @clcto in the original code, `if (i = 0)` fails (`0` is `false`) so execution continues to `if(array[r] > *largest)` . At this point `largest` is an uninitialized pointer, so reading through it causes the access violation.

Answer (score -1):

when the control back from largest()
then stack frame of is now clear in memory.
then system looking for ptr containing address but it cannot find anything, so system terminate this program